# RIOT-OS and multiple executables?

Tags: operating-systems, real-time, embedded-systems

I am brand new to embedded programming and am wondering if [RIOT-OS](http://www.riot-os.org) has the capabilities that my small project requires.

I have 3 executables, *fizz*, *buzz* and *foo*. They all do separate - but very important - things. My understanding with real-time OSes is that you typically:

1. Take your app’s source code and somehow merge/splice it with the RTOSes source code; then
2. You cross-compile this conglomerated source code (again your app + RTOS source) into a binary that is compatible with the ultimate platform/architecture you will run it on; then
3. You flash the binary to the chip using something like UART or SPI, etc.

First, if this understanding is incorrect, can someone please help correct/clarify things for me?

Assuming I'm more or less on target, then I’m wondering if RIOT-OS supports the concept of "*multiple executables*" running when the chip/OS starts up? In other words, is it possible for RIOT-OS to be cross-compiled with, and then at runtime execute, all 3 executables (fizz, buzz and foo)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [RIOT-OS introduction](https://github.com/RIOT-OS/RIOT/wiki/Introduction) and the [RIOT: One OS to rule them all in the IoT](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-00768685/) report.

It looks like you'll make a *single* application (linked with RIOT runtime); this can be your mixture of the three [executables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable), each running it its own threads.

Having an OS supporting several [executables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) seem to require some [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) (or something to separate the executables) and some notion of [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29), which apparently RIOT-OS does not have.

If you have full access to the C source code of your executables (i.e. your three programs), mixing them is in principle easily possible: you just ensure that every program has unique names. You could for example write some script to get the names in each public function (e.g. `aa`, `ab`, `foo` in program `fizz`) and generate a header `fizznames.h` with `#define aa fizz__aa`, `#define ab fizz__ab` etc... to be included in every translation unit of `fizz`, etc... This header could be generated with `nm` feeding some simple `awk` script (or perhaps by your [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) customizing extension to [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)....); then you write a gluing application which would start each *fizz*, *buzz*, *foo* main function in its own thread.
Alternatively, you could play `ld` tricks (e.g. `ld -r`) with your own GNU `ld` script (perhaps using the [visibility](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) function [attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html)) to mix your three programs in a single executable (and you'll still need your own starting function).

You still have to care about communication and synchronization (between *fizz*, *buzz*, *foo*)